gcc Console output newline
I am trying to output to the console starting on a fresh new line, as in, if the line before did not end with a \n then output \n before outputting the given string.
I came up with this, that seems to work ok.
#include <stdio.h>

bool newLine = true;
void Output(const char* str)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        putchar(*str++);
    }
    if (*(str-1) == '\n')
    {
        newLine = true;
    }
    else
    {
        newLine = false;
    }
}
void OutputN(const char* str)
{
    if (!newLine)
    {
        putchar('\n');
        newLine = true;
    }
    Output(str);
}
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Output("."); }
    OutputN("01");
    Output ("23");
    Output (""); // test to see if a blank string works ok
    OutputN("45");
    Output ("67\n");
    Output (""); // test to see if a blank string works ok after \n
    Output ("89");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Output("."); }
    Output ("\n");
    Output(".");
}


reference this thread "C puts() without newline" there is comment that reads
"It works but could be quite inefficient if stdout is not buffered." referring to calling putchar repeatedly in a loop. I amuse to do with buffering and flushing.
my question is, under what circumstances would this become inefficient and is it likely to cause me any problems.
I plan to call this Output generally in place of fputs(str, stdout);
1 on a raspberry pi 5 ruining kdle, and 2 (possibly more likely to have efficiency issues) from a raspberry pi pico that streams its output over serial.

It's only likely to be inefficient if the program turns off buffering with setvbuf(). This is not common, so it's not a big concern.

Instead of calling putchar() in a loop, why not call puts() and then check if the last character of the string is \n?

Pay attention to edge cases. Output willl crash and burn if you pass it an empty string. Also, *(str-1) is a clumsy way of saying str[-1].

I see that you included an empty string in your test code. Unfortunately, the problem with this is that it causes undefined behavior, so the problem won't actually be detected.

thanks, i can generally see where the problems are likely to arise, im just not bright enough to work out how to stop them arising :-)

@Jay "is it likely to cause me any problems." --> I'd suggest instead adjust code so prior prints always append a '\n'.

Instead of looping, use puts() to write the whole string. Then check if the last character is a newline.
You should also check for an empty string, and not do anything. Your code will access outside the array if the string is empty, causing undefined behavior.
void Output(const char* str)
{
    if (str[0] == '\0') { // empty string
        return;
    }
    fputs(str, stdout);
    newLine = str[strlen(str)-1] == '\n';
}


"why not call puts()" --> puts() always appends '\n'.  Perhaps you meant fputs(str,stdout)?

yes, i noticed that to, hopefully @Barmar can replace 'puts(str)' with 'fputs(str, stdout);' but i got what he was getting at.

In case its any use to anyone else, this is what I end up with after @Barmar's input
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

bool OutputNew = true;

void Output(const char* str)
{
    if (str[0] == '\0') { return; }
    fputs(str, stdout);
    fflush(stdout); // flush output even if there is no \n on the end of the string
    OutputNew = (str[strlen(str)-1] == '\n');
}
void OutputN(const char* str)
{
    if (!OutputNew) { putchar('\n'); OutputNew = true; }
    Output(str);
}
void OutputP(const char* format, ...)
{
    if (format[0] == '\0') { return; }
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
    fflush(stdout); // flush output even if there is no \n on the end of the string
    OutputNew = (format[strlen(format)-1] == '\n');
}
void OutputPN(const char* format, ...)
{
    if (!OutputNew) { putchar('\n'); OutputNew = true; }
    if (format[0] == '\0') { return; }
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
    fflush(stdout); // flush output even if there is no \n on the end of the string
    OutputNew = (format[strlen(format)-1] == '\n');
}

